# $\sin n>0$, $a_n=1/n \, ,\sin n<0$, $a_n=-1/n \, , \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Define sequence $a_n$ as: If $\sin n>0$, $a_n=1/n$, and if $\sin n<0$, $a_n=-1/n$.

Does the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converge?

Comment: Yes, but I could not apply it here since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|= \infty$

Answer (score 2):

Use dirichlets test, which says
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i \epsilon_i$$ converges when $a_i$ is a monotone decreasing sequence converging to zero, and the
$$\left|\sum_{i=1}^n \epsilon_i \right|< M$$ for all $n$, (The sum is bounded),
where $\epsilon_i$ is $-1$ if $\sin(i)<0$ and $1$ if $\sin(i)>0$.

As $\sin(n)$ is uniform distributed in $(-1,1)$ you should be able to chose $M=10$ (my own guess is that $4$ would be enough too).

Comment: I don't get how you know M is bounded? You may add 1 many more times than you subtract 1.

Comment: @BradyTrainor Here the choice of signs is according to $\text{sin}$. So you can use the periodicity of the function to show that it is bounded.

Comment: In what sense is the sequence $(\sin n)$ *uniformly distributed* in $(-1, 1)$? Indeed, the fractional part $\{ n/2\pi \}$ of $n / 2\pi$ is equidistributed on $[0, 1]$. But this seemingly strong claim is also insufficient to claim that the partial sum of signs $(\epsilon_i)$ are bounded. So I'm curious if there are some more elaborated results concerning this topic.

Comment: @sos440 yeah you are right, it was more an heuristic, Does it help to split up the stuff in $$\sign(\sin(n)) \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} ? $$ It is bounded between -5 and 6 for $n< 10^7$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis, $10^7$ is still *infinitesimally* small compared to the number of natural numbers, and we do not know how $(s_n)$ will behave for large $n$. Our numerical experiments may help us guess the asymptote, but cannot serve as a proof.

Comment: @sos440 jupp you are right i guess we need to consider some properties of pi here

Answer (score 2):

Define the *sign function* $\mathrm{sgn} : \Bbb{R} \to \{-1, 0, 1\}$ as

$$ \mathrm{sgn}(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \\ -1 & x < 0 \end{cases}. $$

Then we can rephrase $(a_n)$ as

$$ a_n = \frac{\mathrm{sgn}(\sin n)}{n}. $$

Now let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathrm{sgn}(\sin k)$ be the sum of signs. Then by summation by parts,

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{s_{k}-s_{k-1}}{k}
 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{s_{k}}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{s_{k}}{k+1} \\
&= \frac{s_{n}}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{s_{k}}{k(k+1)}.
\end{align*}

From the [Weyl's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_criterion), it follows that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{s_n}{n} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \mathrm{sgn}(\sin x) \, dx = 0. $$

This shows that $s_n = o(n)$. But this alone is insufficient to prove or disprove that the given series converges or not. Numerical calculations of $(s_n)$ up to $n = 10^7$

[image]

shows that the growth of $(s_n)$ is highly suppressed, indicating the possibility that the series converges.